# WeasyPrint HTML to PDF not rendered Images in TEST VM Environment - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, docker, nginx, weasyprint

I am using Django + WeasyPrint for HTML to PDF generation.

In HTML template I am having around 2 SVG files. While running in Development (local) server, it rendered SVG Images when converting HTML to PDF. Whereas in TEST Server(Which runs by using NGINX and Docker Container), it fail to render SVG files. In WeasePrint, I have mentioned my TEST URL (http//test.sampleproject.com:8000) in the base_url. I don't know why it is working in my dev server and not working in TEST Server

My Code.

```
html_string = render_to_string('sample.html', {'data': data})
result = HTML(string=html_string, base_url='http//test.sampleproject.com:8000').write_pdf(presentational_hints=True)
response = HttpResponse(result, content_type='application/pdf')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename={}'.format('sample.pdf')
return response
```

In my Template file I have loaded around 10 images. Ex: 'sample.html' template file:

```
  {% load staticfiles %}
  <img src="{% static 'svg/Logo1.svg' %}" alt="" />
  <img src="{% static 'svg/Logo2.svg' %}" alt="" />
```

Please help me to render the SVG files in the output PDF.

Comment: Weasyprint requires several libraries to be installed at the OS level to run. Have these been installed on the TEST server? It sounds like you might be missing CairoSVG on the TEST server: https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html

Answer (score 0):

I've done some work in the past with Django + Weasyprint and the only time I had issue rendering images was due to the fact that Weasyprint accesses the image in a different way.

I found that I had to add a static endpoint for it to access the files from, as it is requesting the static images externally to Django. Here's how you can enable your static resources to be accessed externally;

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#s-serving-static-files-during-development

Also as FlipperPA mentions, ensure you have all the OS level libraries installed on your server;

https://weasyprint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html

Hope this helps :)